# Custom Gridview Widgets error loading content

Tags: android, gridview

WidgetProvider Class

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews mView = initViews(context, appWidgetManager, widgetId);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, mView);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private RemoteViews initViews(Context context, AppWidgetManager widgetManager, int widgetId) {

    RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.row);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
    mView.setRemoteAdapter(widgetId, R.id.textViewNoteTitle, intent);

    return mView;
}

}
```

WidgetService class

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {

    WidgetDataProvider dataProvider = new WidgetDataProvider(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    return dataProvider;
}

}
```

WidgetDataProvider class

```
public class WidgetDataProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {

ArrayList mCollections = new ArrayList();

Context mContext = null;

public WidgetDataProvider(Context context, Intent intent) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCollections.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
    mView.setTextViewText(R.id.gridView, (CharSequence) mCollections.get(position));
    mView.setTextColor(R.id.gridView, Color.BLACK);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    initData();
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    initData();
}

private void initData() {
    mCollections.clear();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        mCollections.add("ListView item " + i);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}
```

Widget_provider xml

I am getting an error loading content and custom row in which I am using text and image.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: error is problem loading content instead of widget